# trim object property of undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this function that validate my form field

```
export default value => {
  let errors = {}
  if (!value.name) {
    errors.name = 'username is required'
  }
  return errors
}
```

How do I trim the value? above code doesn't do that. Is it a good idea to use `Object.keys` to iterate and trim all the property values?

this is my solution

```
export default value => {
value = Object.entries(value).reduce(
    (null, [key, value]) => ({ [key]: value.trim() }),
    {}
  )
      let errors = {}
      if (!value.name) {
        errors.name = 'username is required'
      }
      return errors
    }
```

Comment: *"How do I trim the value?"* What does your research suggest? For instance, the topic of trimming strings is [well-covered here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+trim+string). *"Is it a good idea to use Object.keys to iterate and trim all the property values?"* That's entirely up to you and your use case. (Also: Ask *one* question per question, not multiple questions.)

Comment: your question is not clear. Need more explanations

Comment: @Aroon updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> yes you can use Object.keys

```
    export default value => {
    Object.keys(value).forEach(val => {
     value[val] = value[val].trim();
    })
  let errors = {}
  if (!value.name) {
    errors.name = 'username is required'
  }
  return errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Triming object means what your question is not clear. I think your function does job of validation with form data.

```js
var profile = {
  'first_name': 'revansiddh',
  'last_name': '',
  'address': 'Solpaur',
  'pincode': '413224'

}


function validate(obj = {}) {
  var error = {}
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((m) => {
    if (obj[m] == '') {
      error = { ...error,
        [m]: m + 'requireed'
      }
    }
  })
  return error
}

console.log("form validation", validate(profile))
```

Is it what you want achieve ?